# How to build and publish expo app using Expo Application Services (EAS)

Tags: expo

How can I build and publish an expo app using Expo application services (EAS)? This is my first build app using EAS. I get an error saying `Your account doesn't have access to Expo Application Services (EAS) features.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay for EAS. I think you can sign up for a free trial, or just do expo build:ios or do expo build:android

Comment: EAS Build is also available for free now